# Azure Blob Inventory: How are costs calculated

Tags: azure

[Here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/storage/blobs/), you see the costs for Azure's Blob Inventory Service. For me it is unclear, how  the costs are calculated. Is it per GB or per 10000 items?
Assuming I have a Blob Storage with 100 items which a size of 1 GB how can I calculate my costs?

[image]

Edit: this question is about running a blob inventory run, not about storage costs.

Comment: Have you looked at the Azure Storage pricing?

Comment: I want to know how much a inventory run costs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what blob inventory does:

> Azure Storage blob inventory provides a list of the containers, blobs,
> blob versions, and snapshots in your storage account, along with their
> associated properties.

The operations it performs are:

- List blob containers
- List blobs (includes blob versions and snapshots)

As such there are 2 REST operations. Each operation returns a maximum of 5000 items.

To calculate the cost, you just need to get the total number of REST operations needed to get this information and get the cost of each kind of operation. Assuming you have just one blob container and that container contains 100 blobs, then there will be 2 operations. Similarly, if there is just one blob container and that container contains 5001 blobs, then there will be 3 operations.

You can check the **Operations and data transfer** section in the link you shared to get the price. The item you would need to consider is **List and Create Container Operations**.

[image]

Comment: Where do you see the 5000? Shouldn't it be 10000?

Comment: 5000 is the number of items returned per REST API call. For example, if you have 6000 blobs in a blob container, to list all blobs in the blob container you will need to make 2 REST API calls - first one will return information about first 5000 blobs and the second one will return information about next 1000 blobs.